# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parquet.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;)V

Tags: apache-spark

Got the following error while running Spark 1.3.1 as well as 1.4.1

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parquet.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;)V
>       at parquet.schema.Types$PrimitiveBuilder.build(Types.java:314)
>       at parquet.schema.Types$PrimitiveBuilder.build(Types.java:232)
>       at parquet.schema.Types$Builder.named(Types.java:210)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$$anonfun$fromDataType$1.apply(ParquetTypes.scala:314)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$$anonfun$fromDataType$1.apply(ParquetTypes.scala:305)
>       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$.fromDataType(ParquetTypes.scala:305)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$$anonfun$4.apply(ParquetTypes.scala:395)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$$anonfun$4.apply(ParquetTypes.scala:394)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$.convertFromAttributes(ParquetTypes.scala:393)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$.writeMetaData(ParquetTypes.scala:440)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache.prepareMetadata(newParquet.scala:260)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache$$anonfun$6.apply(newParquet.scala:276)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache$$anonfun$6.apply(newParquet.scala:269)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache.refresh(newParquet.scala:269)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2.(newParquet.scala:391)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DefaultSource.createRelation(newParquet.scala:98)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DefaultSource.createRelation(newParquet.scala:128)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:240)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateMetastoreDataSourceAsSelect.run(commands.scala:218)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:54)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:54)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.execute(commands.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:1099)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:1099)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1121)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1071)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1037)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1015)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.spark.SparkClient.dataFrameToHiveTable(SparkClient.java:128)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.xflow.operation.sink.DataFrameToPlatformSink.push(DataFrameToPlatformSink.java:79)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.xflow.operation.sink.ASink.operate(ASink.java:24)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.xflow.operation.AOperation.process(AOperation.java:121)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.xflow.flow.executor.ExecutableOp.call(ExecutableOp.java:26)
>       at com.xurmo.ai.xflow.flow.executor.ExecutableOp.call(ExecutableOp.java:15)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

From the log its clear that the class loader is loading some other version of this class.
Can someone please tell me which other jar packages have this class?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue.
There are two jar file in lib directory which contain Precondition Class

```
1.parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0rc3.jar
2.parequet-hadooop-bundle-***.jar (which does not contain checkState method)
```

I remove it only

```
parequet-hadooop-bundle-***.jar
```

file from lib directory and now its working for me.